# Python how to handle imap login when multi threading so not connecting all the time?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, imap

I've wrote my first python requests program and it works.
Im trying to sign up to a particular website, and while I can do it fine, I want to be able to multithread to make the process more efficient.

problem is as part of my program, it connects to gmail and retrieves a login code. To make the functions easier to write, i have say, 5 emails that are forwarded to my imap account. My function then logs into imap and takes note of the original 'To' header to select the email i want and then takes the code i need.

Obviously, when multithreading, ideally I don't want multiple simultaneous connections to the mailbox as I assume this would cause me issues? Or will it? Im going to text it but figured It might cause problems with gmail due to simultaneous connections

Would I have to create an obhect of some sort where my imap process continuously updates perhaps? And then I can try and write my functions to search there instead? or is there an easier way where I can connect to imap at the start and have any threads using that one connection? Not sure of the best way to handle it

Comment: IMAP connections are not multithreaded; they are one socket, so they can only really have one thing going on at a time; that is, the server can only be returning one message body at a time to you, there is no multiplexing.  (There can be pipelining, but I don’t know of any libraries that can effectively share a connection well).  If you want multiple threads to do independent requests, you need independent connections.

Comment: Thanks max, would imap accept multiple connections do you know or would it refuse me for too many requests?

Comment: Because IMAP has a lot of limitations (eg, you can only look at one folder at a time), most servers will accept a _few_ connections for a given user from a given IP.  Many clients use up to around 4 to be able to monitor or download multiple folders.  Accessing several accounts from the same IP, or doing it from a VPS, or rapidly disconnecting and reconnecting are all likely things to trip major sites security protocols.

Comment: Thanks, pity, It's a minor convinience but It's been on my mind all day. I imagine it would be a pain to just have one connection sweep all the data for any 'to' address, store them somehow with the verification codes as a key pair and then have the threads retrieve them/look every 5 seconds until they find a match for their own email property. 
I assume I could do this in theory? If i have a list and i run imap from program start and let it continue until my threads all report success and just do 10 second sweeps to update?

Comment: IMAP has a lot of guarantees; for example, messages are immutable.  Once you’ve looked at a message, you never need to look at it again.  Don’t process UIDs you’ve already seen.  Only downloads headers or fields for new messages, etc.  this is all stuff that can be done on a single thread pretty quickly; if your library and server support it, take advantage of `IDLE` to get notified of new messages, etc.

Comment: So if I create a list. And add my 'to' field (which matches a variable I can compare it to). Along with the code as the value. I can check again I'm 10 secs but ignore ones I already grabbed? I feel idle won't help perhaps because I'll potentially have 20 multi threads all signing up and then waiting for their verification emails that will all be landing randomly. Not sure how I could use idle to prompt the individual threads to pause/continue. As I say Fairly inexperienced. Thanks so much again

Comment: I think you should perhaps abandon the idea of using multithreading to wait, and use a single thread to manage IMAP and perhaps communicate with it queues and such.  Have an IMAP thread always waiting for a new message, when a new message come sin, grab the headers, and if it matches something that's being waited for (in a shared data structure), then send a flag to the waiting thread along with the message body or whatever.

Comment: Thanks again max, not looked into ques etc but will do now

Comment: Max. Apologies again for another message. I have had a look and from what I see, I don't want queues as I don't want the order fixed incase any of my tasks failing. So would the following work?        I multithread my function, then stop where I originally did the imap login, and wait until a dictionary (populated by one imap process as new messages come in) contains a key that matches what they're waiting for? Then continue with rest of function with the new dict values required. That was if 2 tasks fail or the email doesn't come up etc the rest should still finish?

Comment: Sounds like a plan to me.  Though are you really getting so much email that just a producer/consumer relationship wouldn’t work?  Get an email -> process an email.  Keep a list of things you’re interested in (eg, a dict or set as you mentioned).  Having a lot of blocking threads would work, but maybe see if you can do it in a non-blocking manner.  At this point, we’re getting into program design rather than a specific question, which isn’t really on-topic for StackOverflow.  Good luck.

Comment: You are a gent! I probably could to be honest, I have a design now that doesn't seem to block it. It was more me overdeveloping for the experience I guess, atm I do it synchronusly and it doesn't seem to block, it does 3 tasks per minute, I just wanted to go down the path of multi threads as this is probably my first ever project thats anywhere near functional which is keeping me learning (Low attention span). :D